# any script to know all the AWS resources created by certain IAM user

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-resource-group

Good day,
Is there any script or any aws cli command to know which IAM user created what resource in AWS. so that we just enter the IAM user name and it shows all the resources created by that particular IAM user.
thanks in advance.

Comment: How have the resources been created? Console, cli, third party i.e. Terraform?

Answer (score 0):

The service that you're looking for is [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html).

By default, it retains 90 days worth of events for the current account and region, and you can access it from either the Console or [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudtrail/lookup-events.html). You can also configure it to write events to S3, where they're be preserved as long as you want to pay for the storage (this also lets you capture events across all regions, and for every account in an orgnanization).

CloudTrail events can be challenging to search. If you're just looking for events by a specific user, and know that user's access key (here I'm using my access key stored in an environment variable) you can use a query like this:

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes "AttributeKey=AccessKeyId,AttributeValue=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" --query 'Events[].[EventTime,EventName,Username,EventId]' --output table
```

Or, by username:

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes "AttributeKey=Username,AttributeValue=parsifal" --query 'Events[].[EventTime,EventName,Username,EventId]' --output table
```

You can then use `grep` to find the event(s) that interest you, and dig into the details of a specific event with:

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes "AttributeKey=EventId,AttributeValue=8c5a5d8a-9999-9999-9999-a8e4b5213c3d"
```